# Concurrent RDP Access for Users

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

Previously posted questions referred to two user logins simultaneously, I can't even do that. I have already tried allowing unlimited users in gpedit.msc.

How can I allow multiple users to log in at the same time on Windows 10?

Comment: see this [link](https://www.serverwatch.com/server-tutorials/remote-desktop-connections-for-multiple-users-on-windows-10-and-windows-server-2012.html) and this [link](https://www.avoiderrors.net/enable-multiple-logins-windows-7/)

Comment: I'm very interested but i already tried replacing the termsrv.dll file with one that a different website provided but it didn't work - it cut off the Remote Desktop completely. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I still can't get mine to work. Anything i could check or verify such as Group Policy settings etc.?

Comment: When i try to connect to a second user with RDPCheck.exe it tells me the number of connections is limited and all connections are in user, does that provide any clues to why it doesn't work for me?

Comment: I'm on a Windows 8 machine, non-server, non-domain. The instructions for the Registry Editor call for a 0x0 and 0x1 value, is that the same as just a 0 and a 1? Entering an 'x' is not permitted.

Comment: Could someone please help me out with the above question??

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 10, (which is tagged, I'll edit the question to make it more clear), there is a limit of one user on the console at a time.

Comment: So there is absolutely no way of allowing at least 2?

Comment: Not without hacking Windows System files and violating the EULA.

Comment: If i have two user accounts on my PC, can i somehow block only one user from using Remote Desktop while leaving it open for the second users?

Comment: Regarding the above question about multiple users, can i allow that on windows 8?

Comment: @user894407, You could only grant one user access to RDP (this doesn't work if they are both adminsitrators, through... you could still do it, but you'd have to make changes in group policy).  This is of use then:https://serverfault.com/questions/598278/how-to-disable-rdp-access-for-administrator  But no, using Windows 8 will not help.  The only way around this is to use a Windows Server OS.